# Center logo within Vuetify navigation bar

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

My Vue/Vuetify app has a navigation bar with the following elements

1. A hamburger menu
2. An SVG logo that's linked to the homepage
3. Some navigation links

I want to left-align the menu, center the logo, and right-alight the navigation links. Here is the markup I'm using:

```
  <v-app-bar app>
    <!-- hamburger menu --->
    <v-menu>
      <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" />
      </template>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems"
                     :to="menuItem.route"
                     :key="index">
          {{ menuItem.text }}
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>

    <!-- logo --->
    <router-link :to="{name: 'home'}">
      <v-img src="../assets/logo.svg" width="110px" />
    </router-link>

    <!-- navigation links --->
    <v-spacer />

    <router-link v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems"
                 :key="index"
                 :to="menuItem.route">
      {{ menuItem.text }}
    </router-link>
  </v-app-bar>
```

I've made numerous unsuccessful attempts to center the logo, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Could you provide the rendered html and css?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you need to center the logo, no matter how much space the other components take, do the following (But this is gonna be tricky, as it will depend on the length of the router links on the right, and how much space they take)

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-app-bar app>
            <!-- hamburger menu --->
            <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" />
            </template>
            <v-list>
                <v-list-item
                    v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems"
                    :to="menuItem.route"
                    :key="index"
                >{{ menuItem.text }}</v-list-item>
            </v-list>

            <!-- logo --->
            <div class="center-me">
                <router-link :to="{name: 'home'}">
                    <v-img src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="110px" />
                </router-link>
            </div>

            <!-- navigation links --->
            <v-spacer />
            <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                <router-link
                    v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems"
                    :key="index"
                    :to="menuItem.route"
                >{{ menuItem.text }}</router-link>
            </div>
        </v-app-bar>
    </v-app>
</template>

<style scoped>
    .center-me {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
</style>
```

Still, you can use the Flexbox classes provided by Vuetify to distribute the space equally between the three parts, like the following (Also, using the v-spacer around the logo will do the trick)

```
<v-app-bar app>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-space-between align-center" style="width:100%">
    <!-- hamburger menu --->
    <v-menu>
      <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" />
      </template>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems"
          :to="menuItem.route"
          :key="index"
        >{{ menuItem.text }}</v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>

    <!-- logo --->
    <router-link :to="{name: 'home'}">
      <v-img src="../assets/logo.svg" width="110px" />
    </router-link>

    <!-- navigation links --->
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
      <router-link
        v-for="(menuItem, index) in menuItems"
        :key="index"
        :to="menuItem.route"
      >{{ menuItem.text }}</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</v-app-bar>
```

Good luck.

Comment: I guess I need the CSS rules for the class `center-me` in order to use the first solution

Comment: It's in the first solution code I provided, in the <style> section. Scroll down in the code if you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `v-spacer` like this:

```
<v-app-bar>
  <v-menu>
     // some code 
  </v-menu>

  <v-spacer></v-spacer>

  <!-- logo --->
  <router-link :to="{name: 'home'}">
     <v-img src="../assets/logo.svg" width="110px" />
  </router-link>

  <v-spacer></v-spacer>

  <router-link>
    // some code
  </router-link>
</v-app-bar>
```

Comment: That doesn't quite work, it puts an equal amount of horizontal whitespace on the left and right of the logo, but it doesn't center it horizontally within it's parent